# numaif.h: MPOL_LOCAL undeclared for use in mbind

Tags: c, linux-kernel, numa, debian-based, numactl

According to the [`mbind man page`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mbind.2.html), one possible `mode` is `MPOL_LOCAL`, which places the memory region in the same node of the CPU that triggered the allocation:

```
#include <numaif.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>    

#define N 134217728

int main() {
    uint64_t *a = (uint64_t*) malloc(N*sizeof(uint64_t));
    mbind(a, N, MPOL_LOCAL, 0, 0, MPOL_MF_STRICT | MPOL_MF_MOVE);
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

However, the symbol is simply not defined.

```
$ gcc-8 -lnuma example.c
example.c: In function ‘main’:
example.c:10:14: error: ‘MPOL_LOCAL’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘MPOL_MAX’?
  mbind(a, N, MPOL_LOCAL, 0, 0, MPOL_MF_STRICT | MPOL_MF_MOVE);
              ^~~~~~~~~~
              MPOL_MAX
example.c:10:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Changing to e.g. `MPOL_INTERLEAVE` makes it compile and display `Hello world!` just fine.

What's going on here? At this stage I'm 100% puzzled.

I've tried with `gcc`/`g++` 4.9.2, 5 and 8; in three different machines running the kernels `4.17.12+` (no idea where it came from), `4.18.10` (compiled myself) and `4.15.0` (included in latest Linux Mint). `libnuma-dev` is up to date.

Comment: Have you looked at your numaif.h file to see if MPOL_LOCAL is actually defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPOL_LOCAL is declared kernel side in [uapi/linux/mempolicy.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/mempolicy.h#L20) and is equal 4. It's in UAPI, so actually you can `#include <linux/mempolicy.h>`.

MPOL_LOCAL should be declared user side in [numaif.h](https://github.com/numactl/numactl/blob/master/numaif.h) as in the man page. I fail to see why it isn't, alongside with other defines. Also the definition for MPOL_MAX changes - kernel side it is equal to `MPOL_LOCAL + 1 = 5`, but in numaif.h it's equal to `MPOL_INTERLEAVE = 3`. I would expect MPOL_MAX to be either one greater then the maximum MPOL or equal maximum value on both sides, but kernel and user space tool define it differently.

I think it deserves to post an issue to [numactl](https://github.com/numactl/numactl) to notify the developers. According to man page it should defined. I don't know why it isn't.

As for now, I would just

```
#include <numaif.h>
#ifndef MPOL_LOCAL
#define MPOL_LOCAL 4
#endif
```

I have browsed the web to find out how different programs handle this. I think programs just define all MPOL_* symbols themselves, see [hwloc](https://github.com/open-mpi/hwloc/blob/master/hwloc/topology-linux.c) or [stress-ng](https://github.com/ColinIanKing/stress-ng/blob/master/stress-numa.c). [fio](https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/master/fio.h) just defined MPOL_LOCAL themself to be equal 4. Open-mpi even marks that `numaif.h` does not define MPOL_LOCAL and they need to define it, see [here](https://github.com/open-mpi/hwloc-debian/blob/master/src/topology-linux.c#L1400).

Comment: Wow. At this stage I'm even more puzzled. I've filed an issue on their GitHub (https://github.com/numactl/numactl/issues/38). I'll use your workaround in the meantime (or forever) :-) awesome answer; thanks!